# how to use Geneos mail sending function

Tags: geneos

I am using gateway-sql toolkit to get output from multiple view in tabular format.
I wish to send the output to me as it is from Geneos.
How can I do it, kindly help with the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

There is no straightforward rule block function to parse a whole table in Active Console and output it to an email.

Essentially, to do this, you would have to assign each cell value of the table to a variable and build a string using the format() function.

A work around for this (which is also a scalable solution) is to use the Geneos Webslinger to give a HTML table at a given.

[Example Table of Data in Webslinger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSN30.png)

The URL for this page is based on the viewpath, but can be configured to be static. You can further send a rich text email by parsing the source code from this HTML Page (copying the contents of the `<table>` tags)

[Source Code for Webslinger Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJQwl.png)